# Python Module PyBluez Error

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 Server on a Mac OS X (Maverick) and python 2.7.5.
I installed PyBluez and Bluez-libs.  When I type

```
import bluetooth
```

or

```
from bluetooth import *
```

it successfully imports but when I try to run a basic script using the

```
discover_devices()
```

method, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fin.py", line 4, in <module>
    devlist = discover_devices()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 17, in    discover_devices
    sock = _gethcisock ()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 226, in _gethcisock
    raise BluetoothError ("error accessing bluetooth device")
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error accessing bluetooth device
```

and when I type

```
~$ hcitool dev
```

no devices are named.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you run Ubuntu "on a Mac OS X (Maverick) and python 2.7.5"?

Comment: I have an Ubuntu Server partition installed on Oracle VM VirtualBox and that has python 2.7.5+ on it.  I'm using SSH to communicate with it on my Mac which has OS X Maverick.

Comment: You should upgrade your server BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run `discover_devices()`, make sure the 'hci0' is in an UP RUNNING state by running the command:

```
hciconfig hci0 up
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because (most likely) the server doesn't have bluetooth interfaces (what server uses bluetooth anyways?) or it doesn't get detected. The output of `hcitool` being blank points that you don't have bluetooth interfaces connected to the system working as server (if it's a VM, unless it's USB adapter it could not work).

Comment: ok.  I have a bluetooth usb adapter in my MAC.  Is there a way to get Ubuntu to recognize this?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 do it works in a desktop?

Comment: Yes, when I insert the usb into the MAC, the MAC reads it.

Comment: I meant a desktop version of Ubuntu...

Comment: I installed Ubuntu Desktop on the VirtualBox.  I plugged in the bluetooth adapter and it still says `devices: [nothing]`